# Square-Connect GET refunds ignoring time filter

Tags: square-connect

I'm using the Square Connect API to retrieve refunds using the begin/end time filter, and it appears that the begin_time filter is being ignored.

Here is the request:

https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/refunds?begin_time=2014-04-26T00%3A33%3A54Z&end_time=2014-05-26T00%3A33%3A54Z

Here's the response

```
[
{
    "type": "FULL",
    "created_at": "2014-05-21T18:27:59-04:00",
    "processed_at": "2014-05-21T18:28:00-04:00",
    "reason": "Accidental charge",
    "refunded_money": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "amount": -103
    },
    "payment_id": "qNEwqwYPHCfKAIjFtox5S"
},
{
    "type": "FULL",
    "created_at": "2014-05-24T01:00:53-04:00",
    "processed_at": "2014-05-25T19:16:04-04:00",
    "reason": "Accidental charge",
    "refunded_money": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "amount": -123
    },
    "payment_id": "MkJHTnEKHS7larVWAP15S"
}
```

]

Based on my begin_time of 2014-04-26,  I would not expect the results to contain either of the 2 refunds that were returned.

Am I doing something wrong,  or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The `begin_time` and `end_time` parameters of the List Refunds endpoint specify the bounds of a time range. The endpoint returns all refunds that were created within that time range.

In the above example, the time range begins April 26 2014 and ends May 26 2014. The returned refunds were created on May 21 and May 24, both of which fall after April 26 and before May 26. The endpoint appears to be working correctly.

Comment: Sorry,  that was my oversight.